# $ionicScrollDelegate freezes the scroll

Tags: ionic-framework

In my controller i am using $firebaseArray and $ionicScrollDelegate to show messages in a chat. when my $firebaseArray is loaded, i am using the scroll delegate to scroll to the bottom and it works fine, no issues there.

But when a new child is added, i am again using scroll delegate to scroll to bottom, that scrolls down without any issues but it freezes the scroll, i.e i am not able to scroll back to the top

code

chat.html

```
<ion-content delegate-handle="mainScroll">
  //chat list

</ion-content>
```

chat controller

```
app.controller('chatCtrl',function($scope,$firebaseArray,$ionicScrollDelegate){

var chatRef = new Firebase("my ref");


$scope.messages = $firebaseArray(chatRef);

 $scope.messages.$loaded().then(function(){
 $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollBottom(true);
});

 chatRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {

$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollBottom(true);

});


});
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are using android phone to test right? If android I'm pretty sure there have a bug by using animation to scroll to bottom. Have you try to remove the animation by delete 'true' value on the function? Ex:

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollBottom(true);
```

to

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollBottom();
```

Try It.. hope it helps you.

UPDATE (SOLUTION):

Okay I found the solution.. It seem we need to set 'jsScrolling: true' instead of by default is 'jsScrolling: false' for android.

Please modified/edit this on 'ionic-angular.js'

Hope it helps others :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but where exactly do we need to set "jsScrolling:false"

Comment: $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollBottom();Removing true worked for me. :)

Comment: @SukamalDas, could you please accept the answer? :)